# See if users in node.js chat app have a matching message

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js chat app that uses socket.io and other dependencies but I have no db currently.

I would like some advice on how to approach this and how to implement it, as I'm working on an app where when 2 users at some point have a matching message, they don’t have to have the matching message at the same time.

User1 might of said the word "apple" at the start of the chat and user2 might of said apple half through the chat. When this match occurs they both get points. I've been looking around for a good base chat app that might facilitate this but nothing I've found has met that.

Thanks.

Comment: can you comment on the timeframe user1 says apple and user2 says apple half, i.e. do they get points if the other user answers with this like 30seconds later?

Comment: its a game and the aim is to tag an image, when an image pop's up the users have 120 seconds to both come up with a matching tag for the image, both users get points when they have a match, as what the image is, the point is to give some meta-data to an image, so if both users at some point both get a matching message then both get the points, if user1 says apple and user2 never says it or never types something that user1 said then there would be no points and the next image would be loaded.

Comment: still dont get the game quite. is user1 able to see what user2 is typing? because then i would just type apple and then the other one would also type apple and they get a point. sorry dont quite get it :P

Comment: yeah sorry user1 and user 2 cannot see each others messages as they could then cheat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i could implement the whole game. Its clear that you will get the answers from both players. I guess that in your chat programm you'd have something of an identifier to check for the users ID and their chat session, so I'm not going to bother with this. I think that the implementation of sending a new "question" for their matching task shouldnt be a problem by just doing a simple

```
setTimeout(function(){ io.emit('newQuestion', {picture: randomPicture})}, 120000);
```

The string match should be another task. This could be easily done in javascript. As you are just trying to match complete strings, I would go about this as follows. Suppose you have a chat `string1` and chat `string2` corresponding to user1 and user2. From there you will need   to cross reference all words in `string1` with `string2`. For this `string1` has to be broken apart.

```
var string1 = "apple half";
var string2 = "an apple";
var string1Split = string1.split(" ");

var match = false;

for(i=string1Split.length; i--;) {
 result = str.match(/string1Split[i]/g);
 if(result.length > 0 && match == false) {
  match = true;
 }
}

if(match) {
 //add points to it
}
```

I'm not sure if you have  to replace the quotes ' " ' in your `string1Split[i]` but thats just a matter of doing another regexp.

Comment: thanks that clears a bit and one final thing I couldn't get my head around was actually how to store each message a user types and the retrieve and compare a current message entered by user1 for instance and compare that message to see if it matches any of user2's previous messages, if that current message then matches a previous message of user2 then match.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use arrays to store the tags, as they are sent to the server. At the same time you could check those incoming tags against the other user's stored tags.

I'd recommend redis for something like this. It's super fast, and it doesn't seem like you need to store data for long periods of time or keep in any kind of complicated data structure.